# Getting a CastError NaN for a Number

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I get this error

```
{ [CastError: Cast to Number failed for value "NaN" at path "area"]
        message: 'Cast to Number failed for value "NaN" at path "area"',
        name: 'CastError',
        kind: 'Number',
        value: NaN,
        path: 'area' } } }
```

for this code

```
MySchema.methods = {
  updateArea: function (oldArea, newArea) {
    var self = this;
    self.area = self.area - oldArea + newArea;
    return self.save(function (err) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return err;
      }
    });
  }
};
```

However, when I logged the typeof self.area, it gives me number. I was testing and realized that by casting it to a Number, it works sometimes. For example, adding this worked and gave no error:

```
var test = Number(self.area);
self.area = test;
```

so it looked like

```
MySchema.methods = {
  updateArea: function (oldArea, newArea) {
    var self = this;
    self.area = self.area - oldArea + newArea;
    var test = Number(self.area);
    self.area = test;
    return self.save(function (err) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return err;
      }
    });
  }
};
```

However, even simply casting it as a Number earlier gives an error, using a line like

```
self.area = Number(self.area - oldArea + newArea);
```

so that it overall looks like

```
MySchema.methods = {
  updateArea: function (oldArea, newArea) {
    var self = this;
    self.area = Number(self.area - oldArea + newArea);
    return self.save(function (err) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return err;
      }
    });
  }
};
```

still gives the error.

Anyone know what's up?

Comment: Good call - 'oldArea' was undefined. Interesting that 'self.area' still gives a number though, and when I logged the typeof, it still gave 'number'. Do you have any idea why that is?

Also, if you want to post your comment as an answer I'm happy to accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of `oldArea` or `newArea` must not be a number.

If you add a number to something like `undefined` the result is [`NaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN).

```
var n = 5;
n = n + undefined;
// n is now NaN
```

Interestingly, `typeof NaN` is `'number'` which can be confusing as its whole purpose is to indicate that it's not a valid number. :-)

Comment: Ah that is interesting, and makes sense. Thanks!