# How can I get the value of a variable in mongoose?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, discord.js

I'm sorry that this might be a stupid question, but I scoured the internet for 20 minutes straight and could not find any relevant answer. I am trying to get the value of a variable called `cashBalance`. Then with that value, I subtract it from `cashBalance`, essentially making it 0. Then, I add that amount to another variable called `bankBalance`. *P.S.* Just to clear some stuff up this is for a discord bot.

I have tried this code, but I ended up with this error:

Code:

```js
let depositModel = economy.findOne({ userID: message.author.id });

if (!isNaN(parseInt(args[0])) || args[0] === "all") {
    console.log('is a num or all')
    let amt = parseInt(args[0]) 

    if (args[0] === "all") {
        amt = depositModel.cashBalance // error here
    }
}
```

Error:

```js
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: CastError: Cast to Number failed for value "NaN" at path "cashBalance"
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting a CastError NaN for a Number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30966164/getting-a-casterror-nan-for-a-number)

Comment: Are you sure that's the error? Anyway, `findOne` returns a promise, so it should be `let depositModel = await economy.findOne` probably.

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros Yes, I have figured this out myself but I totally forgot about this question! Thanks for all the help guys.

Comment: @MrUpsidown Yes, thanks